# How to give an error message when the internet is off in android?

Tags: android

I am making an app in which users needs internet permission, Now Suppose the User gives internet permission to the app but internet is off so how to give an error message that the internet is off and turn it on.

Comment: This question is off-topic

Comment: Are you want to do this for API calls?

Answer (score 0):

This is how u can do it.

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This method actually checks if device is connected to internet(There is a possibility it's connected to a network but not to internet).

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); //You can replace it with your name
        return !ipAddr.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the ConnectivityManager class to see if the internet is connected. 
ConnectivityManager doesn't need to instantiated, the system one can be used this way -

```
if (isNetworkConnected())
        // The internet is on, go ahead 
else{
        // The internet is not connected, either take them to settings, or ask them to turn it on manually.
}

private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ConnectivityManager to see internet is connected or not.

```
public static boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isAvailable() && activeNetwork.isConnected() && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use this condition

```
if (isConnected())
        // The internet is connected, do something
else{
        // The internet is not connected, do something
}
```

Don't forget add this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I hope can help you.